# Set expiry time for a session field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session

Is there a way in `Rails 3` to expire a field in the session? When I searched for this I only found posts about how to expire the whole session, which I do not want to do.

In my situation I have the following:

```
session["END_DATE"] = @end_date
```

I want to tell `Rails` to expire the field `session["END_DATE"]` after a certain amount of time, which is different and a lot less than the global expiry time for the whole session.

I can always use a cookie instead of a session for that field, but it would be good to have it in the session if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

`session.delete(:end_date)` to delete something(end_date in your case) from your session.

Hope it helps!

Comment: that would work if the session keeps the info when was that field added. In my case i want to expire it at the end of the day. So I could do something like if session["end_date"]["time_added_to_session"] < Date.today session.delete(:end_date) end. Do you know if this exists?

Comment: You can do with simple condition right? `session.delete(:end_date) if session[:end_date] < Date.today`

Comment: I am allowing the user to change that date and I want the user modification to be valid until the end of the day.